# How do I create a macro that takes the selection from a radio button and combo box?

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a project on Excel that uses macros and vba. I am trying to create a macro that inputs the data from a separate worksheet. On this worksheet called "Transferred Emps Form" there are two different groups of radio buttons. One is for Job Rating and has buttons from 1 through 5, and the other is Status which includes part-time, full-time, and contract. Also, it includes a combo box that has four different selections. What code would I use to make a macro that takes the selection from the Job Rating group, Status group, and the combo box so it will appear on a different worksheet when I click the macro button.

So far, all I have is:

```
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!RC[1]"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[1]C"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[2]C[-1]"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[3]C[-2]"
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[4]C[-3]"
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[5]C[-4]"
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Transferred Emps Form'!R[6]C[-5]"
Range("A3").Select
```

but I know that it will not be accurate for the job rating, status, and department.
Thank you.